# Is there a corresponding setup for NUnit's TestCaseSource in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, nunit

While writing unit tests with NUnit, you can provide multiple data input combinations using `TestCaseSourceAttribute`. An example from [NUnit's documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5):

```
private static object[] DivideCases = {
    new object[] {12, 3, 4},
    new object[] {12, 2, 6},
    new object[] {12, 4, 3}
};

[Test, TestCaseSource("DivideCases")]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q) {
    Assert.AreEqual(q, n/d);
}
```

This will run `DivideTest` three times with arguments provided by `DivideCases` field.

Is there a way to achieve a similar setup with Jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this approach works for me.

```
describe("divideTest", function () {
  const testCases = [
    { n: 12, d: 3, q: 4 },
    { n: 12, d: 2, q: 6 },
    { n: 12, d: 4, q: 5 }
  ];

  testCases.forEach(test => {
    it(`should divide ${test.n} by ${test.d} correctly`, () => {
      expect(test.n / test.d).toEqual(test.q);
    });
  });
});
```

I found the solution here https://blog.harveydelaney.com/running-multiple-test-cases-in-jasmine/